# I will have two forms On button click i need to show second form. how to achieve this LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I will have two forms on first form when the users clicks the button icon . In need to show second form . kindly help to achieve this lightning web component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the property if:true={controlBoolean} on the form that you want to display after the click.

Then set the controlBoolean as true when clicking the button icon on the onclick function.

You can find more info in the next link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_conditional

Comment: page is getting loaded and redirects to salesforce classis directly

Comment: Could you post the code of the component? at least the Button onclick handler and the outer  tags of the form you want to render conditionally.

Comment: import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import Lwc_patientforms from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Lwcpatientforms';
export default class Patexforms extends LightningElement {
hamburgericon = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/hamburger_icon.svg';
Nexticon = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/next_icon.svg';
Mapicon = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/map_icon.svg';
homepageillustration = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/homepage_illustration.svg';

@track flag = false;
handleChange() {
    this.flag = true;
}

}

Comment: html
<template >
  <template if:false={flag}>
      
              <a href="login.html">
                <span class="formsIcon" style="background: #FF7E47; border-color: #FF7E47;">
                  
                  <lightning-button-icon  icon-name="utility:photo" checked={flag}  onclick={handleChange}
                  ></lightning-button-icon>
                  
                
      
  </template>
<template if:true={flag}>

this is Form b

</template>
</template>

Comment: Hello, that checked={flag} attribute on the button is making it fail, try next:

<template > 
    <template if:false={flag}> 

         <span class="formsIcon" style="background: #FF7E47; border-color: #FF7E47;">
              <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:photo"  onclick={handleChange} >
            </lightning-button-icon> 
         </span>
    </template>
    <template if:true={flag}> this is Form b 
    </template> 
</template>

Comment: import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc'; 
import Lwc_patientforms from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Lwcpatientforms'; 
export default class Patexforms extends LightningElement { 
    
    hamburgericon = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/hamburger_icon.svg'; 
    Nexticon = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/next_icon.svg'; 
    Mapicon = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/map_icon.svg'; 
    homepageillustration = Lwc_patientforms + '/assets/homepage_illustration.svg'; 
    
    @track flag = false; 
    
    handleChange() { 
        this.flag = true; 
    } 
}

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally show forms/components by using one of the conditional statements:

```
<c-my-component if:true={isFirstFormVisible} />
or
<c-my-component if:false={isFirstFormHidden} />
```

More information can be found in the documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_conditional
and
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/migrate_expressions

Comment: <template>
<template if:true={flag}>
    <div>
        This is form b
        
    </div>
    
</template>

<template if:false={flag}>
<div>
    This is form A
    
</div>
<lightning-button-icon  icon-name="utility:photo" checked={flag}  onclick={handleChange}
                  ></lightning-button-icon>
</template>
</template>          

!!-------Js-------!!!!

Comment: above code is not working let me know what am missing